# Applying a function to a column of a dataset

Tags: dataset

Functions can easily be applied to columns of datasets, as in the documentation it is shown. Now I want to apply a function with parameters to a column, but I get a list rules. E.g.

```
dataset = Dataset[{
   <|"a" -> 1, "b" -> "x", "c" -> {1}|>,
   <|"a" -> 2, "b" -> "y", "c" -> {2, 3}|>,
   <|"a" -> 3, "b" -> "z", "c" -> {3}|>,
   <|"a" -> 4, "b" -> "x", "c" -> {4, 5}|>,
   <|"a" -> 5, "b" -> "y", "c" -> {5, 6, 7}|>,
   <|"a" -> 6, "b" -> "z", "c" -> {}|>}]
```

and

```
func[x_] := x^2
```

and additionally (just an example):

```
lmax[list_List, func] := Module[{temp =  list},  {Max @ temp, func @ (Length@temp)}]
```

If I now do:

```
dataset[All, {"c" -> lmax[#c, func] &}]
```

I get the following:

[image]

So two questions:

1. Why do I get this result.... where are the other columns?
2. How can I manage it to get the dataset with the changed column "c"?

Comment: This has to do with precedence, `"c" -> (lmax[#c, func] &) // FullForm` will show you that your operator is a function. It will transform the entire row. You meant to use the syntax `{"c" -> f}` where only `f` is a function. In order to fix this, in other parts of *Mathematica*, it is common to write `"c" -> (lmax[#c, func] &)`. This fixes the precedence issue but there is another problem with this which I believe is specific to this context, and it throws an error. You can get around it by defining `lmax[func_][list_List] :=...` and using `dataset[All, {"c" -> lmax[func]}]`.

Comment: @Picket: Thanks for the precedence hint. The other remake on a workaround is exactly the one I´m using so far (but I´m still searching a "cleaner" way).

Comment: @Picket: "...the other remark", not "...remake" ;-) funny typo....

Comment: I got it now. The problem isn't only precedence, it's precedence and the fact that you use "#c" instead of "#". It should be `dataset[All, {"c" -> (lmax[#, func] &)}]`

Comment: Great! Times[1000, "Thanks"] @ Picket ;-) This is really a good -> answer!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem with

```
dataset[All, {"c" -> lmax[#c, func] &}]
```

is that it will be interpreted as

```
dataset[All, {("c" -> lmax[#c, func])&}]
```

so you have to explicitly write

```
dataset[All, {"c" -> (lmax[#, func]&)}]
```

to get the precedence right. In this last version I've also written `#` instead of `#c` because the function that you specify in this type of format `{"c" -> f}` will be given the values of the column c, and they will be known simply as `#`.