# Apply function with multiple arguments to column in dataset

Tags: dataset

I have a `Dataset` that requires some cleaning.  Let's consider this data:

```
data = Dataset[{<|"ID" -> "1", "Name" -> "Bob", 
    "Hobbies" -> "cycling, soccer, cooking"|>, <|"ID" -> "2", 
    "Name" -> "Bill", "Hobbies" -> "television, gaming, tech"|>, <|
    "ID" -> "3", "Name" -> "Bob", 
    "Hobbies" -> "reading, writing, juggling"|>}]
```

Most of it is relatively easy such as turning strings into integers.  However, some of columns require multiple functions that may use multiple arguments.  If I want to change the ID field into an integer, I can simply write this:

```
reviseddata = data[All, {"ID" -> ToExpression}]
```

However, this won't work when I need to use multiple arguments for a function such as `StringTrim`.

I originally tried this, but I get a failure:

```
reviseddata = 
 data[All, {"Hobbies" -> StringTrim[StringSplit[#, ","]] &}]
```

This code will perform the functions correctly, but I ended up with a list of rules instead of the full dataset:

```
reviseddata = 
 data[All, {"Hobbies" -> StringTrim[StringSplit[#"Hobbies", ","]] &}]
```

I tried following the advice in [this thread](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/83597/applying-a-function-to-a-column-of-a-dataset), but still ran into issues.

I know I can pull the column, do the functions on all elements, then replace the column, but I was hoping to work within this same syntax for simplicity since I am actually dealing with several similarly formatted datasets.

I am sure it is something obvious that I have missed.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried: reviseddata = data[All, <|#,  "Hobbies" -> StringTrim[StringSplit[#Hobbies, ","]]|> &] ?  I think this may do what you are hoping.

Comment: @MarkR, That is perfect.  Syntax changes a bit, but I can run all changes in one line of code, which is what I was looking for. `reviseddata = 
 data[All, <|#, {"ID" -> ToString[#"ID"], 
     "Hobbies" -> StringTrim[StringSplit[#"Hobbies", ","]]}|> &]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're just discoverring that `&` has very low precedence. Consider:

```
a -> b& //FullForm
```

> Function[Rule[a,b]]

The precedence of `&` is lower than the precedence of "->". So, to fix things, include parentheses:

```
reviseddata = data[All, {"Hobbies" -> (StringTrim[StringSplit[#, ","]] &)}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Carl Woll, I could have sworn I tried that syntax, but apparently not.

Answer (score 1):

Having used Carl's suggestion in my initial work, I eventually found that creating a defined function was the most efficient option (especially if you are going to use it more than once).

```
stringToList[string_]:=StringTrim[StringSplit[string]]

reviseddata = 
 data[All, {"Hobbies" -> stringToList}]
```

While Carl's answer certainly answers my question directly, for future readers, I would recommend the defined function.